# How can i improve my Bidirectional LSTM timeseries forecasting

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am trying to forecast a timeseries and  I am using LSTM for it. But the forecast outside train data is pretty bad. I tried adding layers, changing epochs but couldn't improve. The forecast is completely different than the input. Below is the graph and the code. How can I improve this?

[image]

```
#LSTMTrainData is my scaled input data

n_input=16 
n_output=len(train)+45 
n_features=1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(LSTMTrainData, LSTMTrainData, length=n_input, batch_size=5)
                            
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(40, activation='relu'), input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
model.fit_generator(generator,epochs=40,verbose=0)


#if prediction is greater than train data length it is considered as future prediction

pred_list = []
future_pred_list=[]
                                                
batch = LSTMTrainData[:n_input].reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
forecast_till=n_output
                                                
data_x=LSTMTrainData[n_input:]
data_y=[]

for i in range(forecast_till):
    pre=model.predict(batch)[0]
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0]) 
    batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)
                            
    if (i >= len(data_x)):
       future_pred_list.append(pre)
    else:
       data_y.append(pre)
       test_pred=data_y
```

How can i improve this?

Comment: does bidirectional architecture outperform unidirectional architecture for your model?

Comment: i have many timeseries forecasting to be done. As a whole, bidirectional performs better. But it fails miserably for some